# English to Hindi transliteration for android

Tags: java, android, translation, hindi

public class AndroidTranslate extends Activity {

```
EditText MyInputText;
Button MyTranslateButton;
TextView MyOutputText;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyInputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputText);
    MyTranslateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TranslateButton);
    MyOutputText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.OutputText);

    MyTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener);
}

private Button.OnClickListener MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener 
  = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String InputString;
        String OutputString = null;
        InputString = MyInputText.getText().toString();

        try {
            GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http:\\www.google.com");
            GoogleAPI.setKey(" API KEY");
            OutputString = Translate.DEFAULT.execute(InputString,Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            OutputString = "Error";
        }

         Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "akshar.ttf");

        //final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);
        MyOutputText.setTypeface(customF);
        MyOutputText.setText(OutputString);

    }

};
```

}

this code is running but not showing proper output like 
if my input is "aap kaise ho" it gives output = "आप कैसे हो " 
BUT
wen i give input only "a" or "abc" then output should be "अ" or "अबक" but it is not showing  output like this. for "a" it shows "एक"

can ane one please help to solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be a Android or technical problem but rather the way google translate 'a':
http://translate.google.com/?hl=nl&tab=wT#en|hi|a

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using translation API while trying to achieve transliteration in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show "अ" for "a" because in hindi "a" means "एक". The only way is to achieve this is multiple translation of a word but Right now there is no multiple translation support for a word in google translate api. You can achieve this by a web service which is currently used by google translate in web interface.

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=a&hl=en&sl=en&tl=hi&multires=1&otf=2&pc=0&sc=1
```

You may not receive desired output from this.